# MongoDB - PHP and Full text search

Tags: php, mongodb, full-text-search

I wrote this command:

```
    db.collection.find(
        { $text: {$search: "foo query string"}}, 
        { score: {$meta  : "textScore"} } 
    ).sort({ score:{$meta: "textScore"}})
```

It works fine in `mongo shell`, but I want convert this into `php`. Then I wrote different but the same php query:

```
    $store = $db->collection->find([
        ['$text' => 'foo query string'],
        ['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']]
    ])->sort(['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']]);
```

In this case I get an error:

```
127.0.0.1:27017: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue must have
                 $meta projection for all $meta sort keys
```

Obviously `Index` is created.
I have no idea what is wrong. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your query part, I believe it should be

```
['$text' => ['$search' => 'foo query string']]
```

Comment: Indeed I forgot about it, but the error did not disappear.

Comment: Just found http://stackoverflow.com/a/23159722/5982920 which is pretty extensive, could you check if it sheds any light?

Comment: I have the same code, but I skip sorting right now and it looks like a text search operators don't work "unknown operator: $text"