# Full text search and score sorting MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, fat-free-framework

How would I go about using an answer like this one in F3?

[php mongodb full-text search and sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084243/php-mongodb-full-text-search-and-sort)

EDIT:
I am searching in a title and description. If there is no searchterm it will sort on a field `created_at`. If there ***is*** a searchterm however: sort it on the most relevant.

EDIT: EDIT:
I am also using the pagination plugin if that matters.

Comment: Try to explain a little bit more..

Comment: @S.I. I am searching in a title and description. If there is no searchterm it will sort on a field `created_at`. If there _**is**_ a searchterm however: sort it on the most relevant.

Comment: Define "most relevant". Scoring isn't exactly the same everywhere.

Comment: Well, the question and answer I linked to is what I want. But it isn't working in F3, I just get no results

Comment: Have you added a text index to the collection?

Comment: @ikkez Yeah I did. The searching itself works perfectly. I only would like to sort it based on score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [edge](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core) version of the framework, you'll be able to define a projected field named `score` and use it for sorting.

E.g:

```php
// MongoDB instance
$db=new DB\Mongo('localhost:27017','mydb');

// Define a `score` field here
$fields=['score'=>['$meta'=>'textScore']];

// Mapper instance
$mapper=new DB\Mongo\Mapper($db,'mycollection',$fields);

// Search text and sort by score
$mapper->load(
  ['$text'=>['$search'=>'search text']],
  ['order'=>['score'=>['$meta'=>'textScore']]]
);
```

Comment: How would I go about using this with: [Pagination](https://github.com/ikkez/F3-Sugar/tree/master-v3/Pagination)?

Comment: Well, quoted from the [docs](https://github.com/ikkez/F3-Sugar/tree/master-v3/Pagination#3-paginate-your-records): `$subset = $mapper->paginate($page-1, $limit, $filter, $options);`. With, in your case: `$filter = ['$search'=>'search text']]` and `$options = ['order'=>['score'=>['$meta'=>'textScore']]]`.

Comment: Thanks! Will try when I get home. Looks promising!

Comment: `Can't canonicalize query: BadValue: must have $meta projection for all $meta sort keys` Is what I get. I also changed `$filter = ['$search'=>'search text']]` to `$filter = ['$text'=>['$search'=>'search term']]`

Comment: True. There was a typo in my comment. Does it work without pagination?

Comment: Did you really download the [edge](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/archive/master.zip) version? It should include commit [d918c18](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/commit/d918c1829960b3ca0863ed1af565a9fdd405e8ea) or you'll get the error you're complaining about.

Comment: Really? How can I use that with composer?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline-operator-reference)** to get the documents that have most relevant text score by doing a **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline operation which will match the search term, followed by a **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator pipeline which projects the score fields, and then do another **`$order`** pipeline operation to return most relevant item. The "textScore" **[metadata](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/meta/#behavior)** is available for projections, sorts, and conditions subsequent the **`$match`** stage that includes the **`$text`** operation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { 
               "$text": { 
                     "$search": "search text" 
                } 
         } 
    },
    { 
         "$project": { 
               "_id": 0, 
               "score": { 
                     "$meta": "textScore" 
                } 
          } 
     },
     { 
          "$orderby": { 
               "score" : -1 
               }
     }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know how to use it like this though. My question was: how do I use this in Fat Free Framework. Thanks for your help though